# Visual Studio database project publish fails with "data loss might occur" although all rows have NULL in that column

Tags: database, visual-studio, publish, data-loss

I guess this is an old issue, but does anyone know if it is fixed or addressed by Microsoft.

I have a database project in Visual Studio (.sql) and I want to drop a column when publishing it.
The error is:

```
RAISERROR (N'Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.', 16, 127).
```

The target database *does* have rows in that table, but the column in question only has NULL values.
So it should work, I think.
(I know unchecking "Block on incremental deployment if data loss might occur" is a work-around, but I don't want to turn it off for all tables and columns.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When I have run into this I created a pre-deployment script to drop the column off it exist to work around this issue.

Comment: Thanks @JamesMcShane, but it did not help for me, I stilll get "data loss might occur".
I read somewhere that the schema change analysis is done before running the pre-deployment script. So dropping the column in that script is "too late".